# mux.Vars is empty when using httputil.ReverseProxy

Tags: go, gorilla

I am trying to use gorilla mux and httputil.ReverseProxy together, but when trying to get the mux.Vars it is empty. According to https://golang.org/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go?s=2744:2819#L93 it seems like the http.Request pointer is a shallow copy of the original request, which should still work.

Any ideas?

https://play.golang.org/p/JpjNvEMIFB

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

type route struct {
    match string
    base  string
}

var routes = []route{
    // proxy http://localhost:3000/api/foo/bar => https://api.bar.com/5/foo/bar
    route{match: "/api/{path}", base: "https://api.bar.com/5"},
    route{match: "/sales/{path}", base: "https://sales.bar.com/3"},
}

func NewProxy(r *route) http.Handler {
    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        out, _ := url.Parse(r.base)

        req.URL.Scheme = out.Scheme
        req.URL.Host = out.Host
        req.URL.Path = out.Path + "/" + mux.Vars(req)["path"] // mux Vars are empty here
    }
    return &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}
}

func main() {
    for _, route := range routes {
        http.Handle(route.match, NewProxy(&route))
    }

    log.Println("Listening on port 8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two different problems here.

The first one, you are not using a `mux.Router`, so `gorilla/mux` has not the opportunity to pre-process your request.  In other words, the requests are going directly from `http` package to your reverse proxies. This issue has an easy fix:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
for _, route := range routes {
    r.Handle(route.match, NewProxy(&route))
}
http.Handle("/", r)
```

The second problem is more tricky than the first one. This issue is related to how is `mux` package implemented. If you look `mux.Vars()` implementation, you will see that it uses something called `Context`. A `Context`, as described in the [official documentation](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context), is something that stores values shared during a request lifetime. A simplified Context implementation will be:

```
type Context map[*http.Request]interface{}

func (c Context) Set(req *http.Request, v interface{}) {
    c[req] = v
}

func (c Context) Get(req *http.Request) interface{} {
    return c[req]
}
```

As you see, given a `http.Request`, we can store values in a context. Later we can retrieve these values using the same `Context` and the same `http.Request`. `mux` uses a global `Context` to store the vars parsed in routing process so that you can use the standard `http.request`. But, because `httputil.ReverseProxy` passes a copy of the actual request and `Context` links values by request, this new `Request` has no values in the `Context`.

To fix it, you can implement your own `ReverseProxy` based on `httputil.ReverseProxy`:

```
type MyReverseProxy struct {
    httputil.ReverseProxy
    Director func(inr, outr *http.Request)
}

func (p *MyReverseProxy) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, inr *http.Request) {
    p.ReverseProxy.Director = func(outr *http.Request) {
        p.Director(inr, outr)
    }
    p.ReverseProxy.ServeHTTP(rw, inr)
}

func NewProxy(r *route) http.Handler {
    director := func(inr, outr *http.Request) {
        out, _ := url.Parse(r.base)

        outr.URL.Scheme = out.Scheme
        outr.URL.Host = out.Host
        outr.URL.Path = out.Path + "/" + mux.Vars(inr)["path"] 

        log.Printf("IN VARS: %#v\n", mux.Vars(inr)) // Now inr has proper vars
        log.Printf("OUT VARS: %#v\n", mux.Vars(outr))
    }
    return &MyReverseProxy{Director: director}
```

You can even use `context` and keep `Director` declaration:

```
type MyReverseProxy struct {
    httputil.ReverseProxy
    Director func(req *http.Request)
}

func (p *MyReverseProxy) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, inr *http.Request) {
    p.ReverseProxy.Director = func(outr *http.Request) {
        context.Set(outr, "in_req", inr)
        p.Director(outr)
    }
    p.ReverseProxy.ServeHTTP(rw, inr)
}

func NewProxy(r *route) http.Handler {
    director := func(outr *http.Request) {
        out, _ := url.Parse(r.base)

        inr := context.Get(outr, "in_req").(*http.Request)
        outr.URL.Scheme = out.Scheme
        outr.URL.Host = out.Host
        outr.URL.Path = out.Path + "/" + mux.Vars(inr)["path"]

        log.Printf("IN VARS: %#v\n", mux.Vars(inr)) // Now inr has proper vars
        log.Printf("OUT VARS: %#v\n", mux.Vars(outr))
    }
    return &MyReverseProxy{Director: director}
}
```

Both implementations seem tricky to me. They have to change `httputil.ReverseProxy`'s `Director` in every call. So, I probably accept that `mux` is not a good choice here, and instead I will use some simpler solution:

```
var routes = []route{
    route{match: "/api/", base: "https://api.bar.com/5"},
    route{match: "/sales/", base: "https://sales.bar.com/3"},
}

func NewProxy(r *route) http.Handler {
    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        out, _ := url.Parse(r.base)

        req.URL.Scheme = out.Scheme
        req.URL.Host = out.Host
        req.URL.Path = out.Path + "/" + strings.TrimPrefix(req.URL.Path, r.match)
    }
    return &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}
}
```

You can read [`mux` source code](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/master/regexp.go) to implement a complex solution based on regular expressions.

Comment: Oops, not using the mux router, was last minute attempt to work around the problem, but it looks like I didn't undo far back enough before asking the question.

Comment: I was unaware that context played a part.  Not using the mux router and trimming off the prefix, like you did in the last example, was the way I wanted to go but didn't due to the need to match the urls with a regex. Maybe, as you suggested, going that route would make things much cleaner. Thanks for the help